# Run a function multiple times with different arguments sequentially in Node Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, q

I have an array with values and I want to run a single function with a callback with each of the array's values as an argument sequentially. Meaning, run the function with the first cell's value, when it finishes run the function with the second's cell value etc. I tried with Q and I can't seem to find a way to do it with arguments, it keeps calling the function.

Example:

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,5]

var func1 = function(num){
  setTimeout(function(){
    console.log(num+num);
  }, 3000);
}
```

I want to run the function with 1 as argument, when it finishes run with 2 as argument etc

Please notice that I want to run it sequentially.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use array.map

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,5]

var func1 = function(num){
  console.log(num+num);
}
array.map(func1)
```

Comment: Is there a reason for using .map over .forEach ? (all I can see is a shorter method name)

Comment: The function has a callback, I forgot to mention it

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a forEach

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,5]
var func1 = function(num){
  console.log(num+num);
}
array.forEach(func1);
```

And with Promise somethig like (not working code, just giving ideas) :

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,5]
var func1 = function(num){
     var p = new Deferred();
     setTimeout(function(){
         console.log(num+num);
         p.resolve(num+num)
     }, 3000);
     return p;
}
var count = 0;
function next() {
    func1(array[count++]).then(next);
}
```

Comment: The function has a callback, I forgot to mention it

Comment: The you have to use multiple Promise and to chain them

Comment: Can you provide a code snippet ? I tried to do it with Q.